# How do I use radio buttons in a ListView Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of varieties `[Chocolate, Strawberry, Vanilla]`
This list can change depending on the menu item ordered (i.e. `[BBQ, Medium, Peri-Peri, Lemon & Herb]`)

My current code which display the button correctly but is not functional is:

```
               ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: varietyList.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          return GFRadioListTile(
                            titleText: varietyList[index],
                            size: 25,
                            activeBorderColor: Colors.black,
                            focusColor: Colors.black,
                            type: GFRadioType.basic,
                            value: 0,
                            groupValue: 1,
                            onChanged: (value) {},
                            inactiveIcon: null,
                          );
                        })),
```

Where ```int number = 20'''. This variable and amount was based off another post where the code looked as follow:

```
ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: varietyList.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                          return RadioListTile(
                            value: index,
                            groupValue: number,
                            onChanged: (ind) => setState(() => number = ind),
                          );
                        })),
```

But it says "A value of type 'Object?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'."

How can I get the radio button functional?

Answer (score 0):

to fix the "object cant be int" problem I had to add `as int` for the `ind` object.

```
GFRadioListTile(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            radioColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 138, 5, 5),
                            title: Text(
                              varietyList[index],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 25, color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            size: 28,
                            activeBorderColor: Colors.black,
                            focusColor: Colors.black,
                            type: GFRadioType.basic,
                            value: index,
                            groupValue: number,
                            onChanged: (ind) =>
                                setState(() => number = ind! as int),
                            inactiveIcon: null,
                          );
```